# how to display the Text file or Properties file data in angularjs and save down the file in same place

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I wanted to display the data of Properties file or Text file from the server folder in front end AngularJS and then save down the same file in same path.

Currently I am using just download the file and edit the file and then uploaded the same file in given targeted path by using given code.

```
new Blob([data], { type: 'application/type of file' }); saveAs(file, type of file);
```

How to display the Text file or Properties file data in AngularJS and save down the file in same place?

Comment: so ... this is actually an angularJS issue?

Comment: no idea, i am querying like Is there any way do this in angularjs?

Comment: just i wanted to edit the file on the fly and save down..

Comment: Is this file public to the internet? How will you handle security? You probably need to look into some kind of web app to talk to, if you dont know where to start take a look at nodejs and express.

Comment: Already i had https security for this application and i am not worried about security ,just i need solution for this .